# Questions on how to create a game similar to Pac-Man

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to make a game that will be similar to [Pac-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man) from scratch. I don't want to use a games engine either, just plain old [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).

Basically the game would consist of a map that fits the screen, walls within the map, food, enemies and a player.

I just wanted to know what the best way forward would be. I plan on creating the map first, and then doing everything else after that. Where should I begin?

Comment: If you want to actually replicate the AI of the ghosts, there's an awesomely detailed discussion here: http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/2wKX2M/gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I plan on creating the map first

Keeping in mind that you'll probably want several maps, you might want to create a map *editor* first, which would let you place "wall" graphics and define the paths along which the player & ghosts are allowed to travel. If you define those paths with nodes at each intersection, the ghost AI becomes easy to solve with [A* path finding](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/). Your map editor can use the distance between intersections to calculate the "weight" of each path segment.

Comment: thanks, but how could I do this? Are there any examples online on how I could do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Pac-Man only had one map. Maybe you're thinking of Ms. Pac-Man, the far superior game ;)

Comment: @XcodeDev - I'd start with the "Sketch" example that's included with Xcode. It's not a game, but it's a bare-bones drawing app that could form a good foundation on which to build a map editor.

Comment: @quixoto - Right on both counts! Ms. Pac-Man had multiple maps and randomized ghost movement, both of which made for a *much* better game.